# How to navigate to specific MaterialPageRoute in app from a notification in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to navigate to specific MaterialPageRoute in app from notification click? I have notifications configured in the main screen:

```
void _configureNotifications() {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();
  _firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      _goToDeeplyNestedView();
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      _goToDeeplyNestedView();
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      _goToDeeplyNestedView();
    },
  );
}

_goToDeeplyNestedView() {
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => DeeplyNestedView()));
}
```

The problem is, that when i configure it like this, it woks only from Widget where i configured notifications (I guess it's because of using 'context' in 
 Navigator.push(). Is there some way to access to MaterialPageRoute from anywhere in the app without using any context?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There aren't very many cases where a GlobalKey is a good idea to use, but this might be one of them.

When you build your `MaterialApp` (which I assume you're using), you can pass in a [`navigatorKey`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp/navigatorKey.html) parameter which specifies the key to use for the navigator. You can then use this key to access the navigator's state. That would look something like this:

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: "Main Navigator");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      home: new Scaffold(
        endDrawer: Drawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: new Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And then to use it you access the navigatorKey.currentContext:

```
_goToDeeplyNestedView() {
  navigatorKey.currentState.push(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DeeplyNestedView())
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this setup, but I am still not getting the Page specified in the onResume / onLaunch page to be displayed. Does the app always go through main.dart? If so, could routing defined there, override the routing setup in onLaunch/onResume?

Comment: @dazza5000, that is whatI think I'm facing too, but not sure yet. Did you manage to find out? And got it working?

Comment: I also tried this setup, but it is not working. It is not opening the mentioned screen inside ```onResume``` call back method. It simply opens the last screen before the app goes to the background mode.

Comment: @DhavalKansara Whoops, looking at this now I don't think what I had there would actually work any more. I've edited it to directly use the NavigatorState - try that instead.

Comment: Yeap ```navigatorKey.currentState.push(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => DeeplyNestedView())
  );``` works for me.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie can you please let me know what are the cases when this might not be a recommended approach to handle notification navigation. Also, Can you look in to this issue which is not working fine with this solution?

thanks for yout time.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize `navigatorState` `globalkey`

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: "Main Navigator");

navigatorKey.currentState.push(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => classname())
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue and fixed it using the below code :

1. Creating 1 global key like :

   ```
   final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey();
   ```
2. Assigning the key to Scaffold in build method :

   ```
   return Scaffold( key: _scaffoldKey,
   appBar: Container(), body:
   Container() );
   ```
3. printing ('something') before this to make sure your app is reaching to below code:

   ```
   Navigator.push(
           _scaffoldKey.currentContext,
           MaterialPageRoute(
               builder: ( _) =>
                   NotificationDetailEn(notificationModel: model)));
   ```

I think it will be helpful.