# How to open specific activity on click of push notification from Firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm getting push notification using firebase messaging service in my flutter application.I need to redirect the app to specific activity when I clicks the notification. Could you people suggest some ideas please? Thanks in advance.

This is the code I tried.

```
var initializationSettingsAndroid = new AndroidInitializationSettings(
    '@mipmap/ic_launcher'); // Notification Initialization for android
var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings(); // Notification Initialization for IOS
var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
    initializationSettingsAndroid,
    initializationSettingsIOS); //Initialization done according to their platform
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);


firebaseMessaging
    .configure( //  handling notification while app is in foreground
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('onlaunch');
    //navigateTo(message);
    Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> new Credits()));

  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('onmesage $message');
    print('onResume');
  //  navigateTo(message);
    Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> new Credits()));

  },
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

    print('onmesage $message');
      body = message['notification']['body'];
      title = message['notification']['title'];
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), (){});

    showNotificationWithDefaultSound(message);
      print("title: $title");
      print("body: $body");



    //print("${message['data']['screen']}");
    //Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(message['data']['screen']);

  },

);

//Permission for IOS
firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(

    const IosNotificationSettings(
        alert: true,
        sound: true,
        badge: true
    )
);
firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((
    IosNotificationSettings settings) {
  print("IOS");
});

//geting token from the app
firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
  tokenId = token;
  print(tokenId);
});
```

//

Comment: See the [plugin example app](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart) for expected usage.

Comment: Could you please tell me the specific way

Comment: As shown in the example app, use one of the `Navigator.push...` variants.

Comment: I'll look into it.Thank u

Comment: I tried. But it doesn't take me to that activity. Any other suggestions please?

Answer (score -3):

Firebase messaging object provide you a configure method in you have `onMessage`, `onResume` and `onLaunch` where you can run code of your will. For your requirement I believe you have to call new page/activity such that when your user clicks on notification (when app is terminated i.e not in foreground and background) it will launch that page instead of main page. Implement this code in `initState()` of the root page

```
final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

_firebaseMessaging.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async{
         Print('on message $message'); 
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print('on resume $message');
        },
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print('on launch $message');
          //Call your pageRoute here
        },
      );
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I tried it. But it doesn't go to that specific activity.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the code you have tried. Such that It can be easy for me and others to get a proper idea of what you have done also they can answer it easily

Comment: Sorry @deepan I was totally busy and unable to spend time on this. If you haven't got the answer for this, here is the accepted answer to navigate from notification. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52190314/10250044 I haven't tested it out. Have a look.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I'll look into it.