# Flutter FCM Push Notificaiton Not Working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working in a flutter app that uses Firebase Push Notification. I have a problem is that onMessage I receive data from Firebase but problem is that the only printing the data is working fine but not Navigating to other screen.

```
_configureFirebaseMessageing() {
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

        print('\n\n\n message from fcm  \n $message\n\n\n\n');
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.FirstProfile);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {


        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context){
          return NativationPage("this is from main ON Resume ${message['data']['title']}");
        }));


      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context){
          return NativationPage("this is from main ON Resume ${message['data']['title']}");
        }));
        
      },

    );
  }
```

This is my code and yes only printing data on the console is working and navigation to other screen is not working on all the three onMessage, onLaunch, and onResume.

And I have an error in console :

```
E/FlutterFcmService( 2445): Fatal: failed to find callback
```

And the second error is

```
w/firebasemessaging( 2445): missing default notification channel metadata in android manifest. default value will be used.
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Navigation:**

I think it's a context issue inside **onMessage**. You have to define **navigatorKey** inside **MaterialApp** widget, then you can access current context inside **onMessage** using **navigatorKey.currentContext**.

For further details you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52190314/13378076).

**For Error / Warning:**

Error and Warning is because you have missed some plugin configuration. Do all as mention [here](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)